# Why is my very simple .exe flagged as dangerous every where?

Tags: installation, virus

Im not a programmer so bear with me but I have to touch programmation every so often. That being said, I made a very simple setup file using "Inno setup" to install replace/add a couple of files in a drawing software they use. In other words, Im updating client's software with our lastest database.

So, the problem is that my setup is flagged by everything as potentially dangerous. I read about certification and signing files but im not too sure what it is about. The thing is its only for less than 10 people and I dont see how I could justify paying for a certification for something so minimal.

So, am I missing something? What are my options?

```
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "Starwall Data"
#define MyAppVersion "1.00"
#define MyAppPublisher "Starwall"
#define MyAppURL "https://www.starwall.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "Starwall_DataBase_BaseDonnee_v1.00"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{8196A244-79C9-4E13-BD8B-43607CD2C5C2}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
CreateAppDir=no
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputBaseFilename=Starwall_DataBase_Basedonee_Setup
SetupIconFile=D:\MB_WIP\File\starwall_ico.ico
Password=
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
OutputDir=D:\MB_WIP

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "french"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\PricesByQty_Starwall.xlsm" ; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\PricesByQty_Starwall.txt" ; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\lib\Starwall-2019~1.l32"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\lib" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\lib\Starwall-2019~1.msg"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\lib" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\lib\Starwall-2019~1.ndx"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\lib" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Models\Classic_2019.aff"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Models" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Models\Classic_VerreCentre_CenteredGlass.aff"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Models" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Models\Classic_VerreColle_SeamlessGlass.aff"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Models" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Template\Feuille Conventionnelle PMA.msf"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Template" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Template\Feuille Conventionnelle PMA.msh"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Template" ; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Template\Feuille Conventionnelle PMA.mst"; DestDir: "C:\Program Files (x86)\LOGItram\datas\Template" ; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Some information on SmartScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409187/how-to-get-windows-smart-screen-to-trust-my-installer#comment105021749_59409187). I am not sure what software flags your setup. There could be others.

Answer (score 1):

What might help you is to [create a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84847/how-do-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-code-signing-on-windows) and use that to sign the installer. It is free.

If you have only 10 users, then you can also send the certificate and instruct them to register it on their machines. This way, when they install the setup package the OS will see it is from a trusted certificate.

Comment: Thank you I will try this out and then upvote if it works! :P